# Swipe Gestures to corners like upper right corner, upper left corner

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, uigesturerecognizer

UISwipeGestureRecognizer only works for four directions i.e. up, down, right and left. I need to implement the swipe gestures to corners as well, like upper right corner, upper left corner, lower left corner and lower right corner. Is there any other way to do this rather than using UISwipeGestureRecognizer ? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a swipe gesture recognizer that supports diagonal directions as well I suggest you create a custom gesture recognizer. It isn't that hard. You can find examples on Github. One that I'm aware of is called KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer. It supports rotation gestures using one finger. That's different from what you want but it is an illustration of how to create a custom gesture recognizer.

You might even find a diagonal swipe gesture recognizer that somebody has already written on Github.

Edit: A quick search on Github revealed a project called [DMCrookedSwiper](https://github.com/masuhara/DMCrookedSwiper).